# How to store object value in Flutter secure storage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-secure-storage

I have this error when I run App.

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Map<String, dynamic>' 
has no instance method 'toJson'
```

This is my Code

```
await LocalStorage().addStorage('currentUser', json.encode(jsonResponse['data'][0].toJson()));
```

Comment: How are you getting the jsonResponse? Isn't it already a map? I think you can just remove .toJson() and it should work.

Comment: Yes, thank's a lot, It work fine when I remove .toJson

Comment: Great, I'll post it as an answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't know how you're parsing your JSON, but I would assume jsonResponse['data'] is already a map and does not require you to call .toJson(). The following should work:

```
await LocalStorage().addStorage('currentUser', json.encode(jsonResponse['data'][0]));
```